# How to simulate orientationchange to get css data?

Tags: jquery, media-queries

I have following two media queries

```
@media screen and (orientation : portrait) {
   .rect {width:100px;}
}

@media screen and (orientation : landscape) {
   .rect {width:200px;}
}
```

When I launch `index.php` I need to get two variables instantly e.g.

```
var rect_portrait = width //  when orientation is portrait (100 px)
var rect_landscape = width //  when orientation is landscape (200 px)
```

How can it be achieved? Thank you in advance

Comment: landscape_width = portrait_height; landscape_height = portrait_width;

Comment: Andrew forgive me for my low jQuery skills but how can I use the solution you offered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go!

```
landscape_height = $(window).innerHeight();
landscape_width  = $(window).innerWidth();
```

Now you can decide portrait vs portrait as follows:

```
if(landscape_height < landscape_width){
    console.log('landscape');
    //do something
}else if(landscape_height > landscape_width){
    console.log('portrait');
    //do somethihng
}
```

Now to simulate reverse the condition logic of detecting landscape vs portrait

Comment: Thanks a lot Anubhab!